# Does jQuery have an equivalent to dojo.require?

Tags: jquery, dojo, loader

jQuery is great especially its plugin but I do not like to add a lot of script tags in my html. Is there something similar to dojo.require? So I can manage those plugins easier and cleaner.

Answer (score 10):

jQuery.require does not exist in 1.4, it was in an commit to the tree while 1.4 was being developed but removed before the final release.

[RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) is a loader that has given special care to work with jQuery. It has its roots in the dojo.require, but it follows CommonJS idioms and optimized for in-browser use.

Disclaimer, I am the main developer of RequireJS.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. `jQuery.require` in 1.4 or [Lazy loader](http://code.google.com/p/ajaxsoft/wiki/xLazyLoader) in 1.3